# Ubuntu 18.04 Steam dosen't start AMD Graphics

Tags: graphics, steam, amdgpu

I am trying to get Steam to start on my 64bit Ubuntu. I downloaded the package from the Steam website and installed it. I also installed the AMD Graphics drivers version 18.20 for ubuntu 18.04 from here: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20.
this is what I get when start steam in the terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/steve/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 828: /home/steve/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/run.sh: No such file or directory
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
amdgpu_device_initialize: DRM version is 2.50.0 but this driver is only compatible with 3.x.x.
amdgpu_device_initialize: DRM version is 2.50.0 but this driver is only compatible with 3.x.x.
crash_20190115172028_1.dmp[6644]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20190115172028_1.dmp
crash_20190115172028_1.dmp[6644]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
crash_20190115172028_1.dmp[6644]: error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
crash_20190115172028_1.dmp[6644]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20190115172028_1.dmp'', upload no: ''libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory''
/home/steve/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 889:  6641 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```